# Sending email with node using nodemailer on digitalocean server

Tags: node.js, email, nodemailer

I am using the following function to send an email with node

```
   Mail.sendMail({
     to: `${obj.nome} <${obj.email}>`,
     subject: 'Process Status',
     template: 'processStatus',
     context: {
         nome: obj.name,
         processo: processNumber,
         descricao_status: req.body.status,
     },
    });
```

those are my SMTP settings in my .env file

```
MAIL_HOST=email-ssl.com.br
MAIL_PORT=465:1
MAIL_USER= ...
MAIL_PASS= ...
```

when I test sending e-mail using my machine, locally, I can send e-mails correctly, but when using direct sending on the server, I'm using digitalocean, it doesn't work, does anyone have any idea what can to be ? or something that I can check?

another question is, why do i have to use this: 1? already tested without the same and does not work